# What species of dinosaur made these 3 toed 6 inch long tracks?

Tags: animal-tracks, fossil-identification, dinosaurs

With some friends, I saw some dinosaur  tracks in Wyoming that looked like this,

[image: Dinosaur track]

Can anyone identify what type of dinosaur made these tracks?

Comment: I'm not a tracker, but have you considered looking at it as a depression with small pawprints at one end? From that perspective, it resembles a hare.

Comment: That's called a "hand".  It belongs to a particular species of homonid that often parasitizes larger 4-wheeled hydrocarbon feeders.

Comment: I would ask your local museum - they will likely have an expert familiar with local fossils.

Comment: I'm having difficulty viewing this as a track, were there others on the same rock slab?

Comment: @NateW There were a couple of others on the same slab

Comment: I'm very curious what this is now, but I can't really see it as a dinosaur track. A track would usually be preserved as an indent of the foot shape in the ground, while here the "three toed thingy" seems to be sticking out of the rock. It also looks like a cartoon drawing of a bird foot rather than anything that can carry weight. Do you have any more pictures, like one that shows how the different tracks on the same slab of rock line up? Asking your local museum might indeed be the best bet, if it's a known fossil they might know about it, if it's unknown they might be interested.

Comment: @Monster Technically its a natural cast, not the actual track. That's why its sticking out of the rock.

Comment: I think in order to identify this, it would be very useful to know where the track was found and what kind of rock it was set in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shape of that track reminds me of an [ornithopod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopod). There can be some confusion as to how to identify specifically *which* ornithopod might have made that track ([*Manus track preservation bias as a key factor for assessing trackmaker identity and quadrupedalism in basal ornithopods*, Castanera D, Vila B, Razzolini NL, Falkingham PL, Canudo JI, Manning PL, Galobart A - PLoS ONE (2013)](https://openi.nlm.nih.gov/detailedresult.php?img=PMC3551957_pone.0054177.g011&req=4)), but there is a much more clear method for determining what order the animal belonged to:

> The well-preserved track of a large Ornithopod, a plant-eater should lack distinctive claw marks.  The ends of the toes should be more blunt and rounded in appearance.  The toes tend to be quite wide and the foot proportions are different.  For example, the foot may be much wider.  The wider pes as a proportion of overall foot length gives the track a “u shape”.
>   [image]

[Via Everything Dinosaur](https://blog.everythingdinosaur.co.uk/blog/_archives/2017/06/17/theropod-tracks-and-ornithopod-tracks.html)

**tl;dr: I would assume an herbavore, specifically of the clade "ornithopoda", such as [iguanodontia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iguanodontia).**

*Edit:* I found another paper discussing tracks very much like the ones you found: [*Tridactyl dinosaur footprints from the Morrison Formation (Upper Jurassic) of northeast Wyoming*, John R. Foster & Martin G. Lockley (2008) Ichnos, 4:1, 35-41, DOI: 10.1080/10420949509380112](https://www.academia.edu/230512/Tridactyl_dinosaur_footprints_from_the_Morrison_Formation_Upper_Jurassic_of_northeast_Wyoming)

Comment: Great answer!  You might also be interested in the related question [Are there resources for identifying dinosaur tracks?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/19100/are-there-resources-for-identifying-dinosaur-tracks)

Comment: @JamesJenkins thank you! I'll check that question out as well.