# What do Tyrannosaur dinosaur tracks look like?

Tags: animal-tracks, dinosaurs, fossil-identification

One of the genera of dinosaurs is the [Tyrannosaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus), which includes the famous T-Rex.

What do the tracks of this type of dinosaur look like?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek this been discussed, see https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1163/are-questions-about-tracking-on-topic-for-this-site for some ot the deiscussion currently there is not a communitty decision to put these questions of topic.  See also this related question and great answer https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16972

Comment: Dinosaurs seems a stretch, fossils though seems more fitting.

Comment: @Liam dinosaur tracks are fossils

Comment: To close voters see my [rebutle here](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1178/4079)

Comment: Being from the part of the world where most Dinosaur fossils have been found, I agree dinosaur fossils should be on-topic in the great outdoors. Where else are you going to find them? I'm only a 3 hour drive from Dinosaur Provincial Park, and not too long ago they some hikers made a significant fossil find up in Kootenay National Park. I find fossils every time I go scree climbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the tyrannosaurus dinosaurs are in the suborder [Theropoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theropoda), and were [bipedal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipedalism), which is a fancy way of saying that they walked on two feet.

They had [three toes and one dewclaw.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:T_Rex_Leg_Bones.png) The ones found in British Columbia were over [2 feet long and over 5 feet between tracks](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/animals/a10933/tyrannosaurus-trackways-reveal-a-dinosaurs-walk-17016027/).

Finally, these tracks are incredibly rare with discoveries in,

- 1 track [1983 in New Mexico](https://www.upi.com/T-rex-tracks-preserved-in-New-Mexico/61201247494170/)
- 1 track in [Montana in 2007](https://www.livescience.com/1939-tyrannosaur-footprint-montana.html)
- 1 track and another partial track in [New Mexic in 2009](https://www.upi.com/T-rex-tracks-preserved-in-New-Mexico/61201247494170/) on the same ranch as the one in 1983.
- 7 tracks in [British Columbia in 2011.](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/animals/a10933/tyrannosaurus-trackways-reveal-a-dinosaurs-walk-17016027/)
- 3 tracks in [Wyoming in 2016](http://westerndigs.org/tyrannosaur-tracks-discovered-in-wyoming-reveal-dinosaurs-speed/)

It's also worth pointing out that being more specific than this is hard, with some tracks being either from a [Nanotyrannus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotyrannus) or a [T-Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus) and they aren't even certain if those are two different types of dinosaurs or [Nanotyrannus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanotyrannus) is a juvenile [T-Rex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus).

As far as pictures go,

From New Mexico,

[image: tyrannosaurus track]

[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Philmont_Scout_Ranch_Tyrannosaurus_footprint.jpg)

From British Columbia

[image]

[Image Source](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0103613)

From Wyoming

[image]

[Image source](http://westerndigs.org/tyrannosaur-tracks-discovered-in-wyoming-reveal-dinosaurs-speed/)

If you are still looking for more information, I would suggest this research paper.

[A ‘Terror of Tyrannosaurs’: The First Trackways of Tyrannosaurids and Evidence of Gregariousness and Pathology in Tyrannosauridae](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0103613)